# Knowing the length of a key in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am working with JavaScript and I am trying to know the length of values of a key. My thought is using `forEach` but it is not working. What I mean is like knowing the number of values in audi (that will be 2. Ford will return 2. Kia will return 1). My dataset is below and thanks in advance:

```
const object1 = {
  audi:
   [ { make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2012' },   
     { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' } ],
  ford:
   [ { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' },
     { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' } ],
  kia: [ { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' } ] }
```

Comment: `let audiCount = object1.audi.length, fordCount = object1.ford.length, kiaCount = obj.kia.length;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Comment: @Karan It is a different question. I already know how to loop an object by using the length of the object.

Comment: @StackSlave. Works well. Thanks.

Comment: No hard feeling for you but check all of your answers. You will see they have `loop` over `object` and then simply get `.length` from `values`. That question is not the same but that will provide enough info which can solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use the length property of Arrays.

So in your case, `object1.audi.length` will give you 2

To get all the lengths, you could do the follwing

```
let keyLengths = {}
Object.keys(object1).forEach(key => {
  keyLengths[key] = object1[key].length
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here: use `Object.values` and then just get the length with `value.length`

```js
const object1 = {
  audi:
   [ { make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2012' },   
     { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' } ],
  ford:
   [ { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' },
     { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' } ],
  kia: [ { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' } ] }
  
  Object.values(object1).forEach(value => {
     let length = value.length;
     console.log(length);
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through `Object.keys()` ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)), and it supports in most browsers (see in *Browser compatibility* section)

```js
const object1 = {
  audi: [
    { make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2012' },
    { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' }
  ],
  ford: [
    { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' },
    { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' }
  ],
  kia: [{ make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' }]
}

Object.keys(object1).forEach(key => {
  console.log(key, object1[key].length)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a `for in` loop, to get them all:

```js
const object1 = {
  audi:
   [ { make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2012' },   
     { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' } ],
  ford:
   [ { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' },
     { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' } ],
  kia: 
   [ { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' } ]
}
for(let k in object1){
  console.log(k+'Count = '+object1[k].length);
}
```